# C# Reflection Property.GetValue() Problem

Tags: c#, reflection

I am having a problem with the following code:

```
int errorCount = 0;
foreach (var cinf in client.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var vinf = viewModel.GetType().GetProperty(cinf.Name);
    if (vinf != null)
    {
        if (cinf.GetValue(client, null) != vinf.GetValue(viewModel, null))
        {
            errorCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

It's for an automated test to see whether mapping a model object from a DTO has worked.  If I use the more cumbersome approch of writing this for each property:

```
Assert.AreEqual(viewModel.ClientCompanyID, client.ClientCompanyID);
```

This works fine.

The problem is: the reflection code evaluates "if val1 != val2" statement incorrectly (or so it seems).  If I step through this code, the evaluation basically says "1 does not equal 1", and incorrectly adds an error.  Furthermore, if I test this with this code, I get the same seemingly false result:

```
var clientEx = client.GetType().GetProperty("ClientCompanyID");
var viewModelEx = viewModel.GetType().GetProperty("ClientCompanyID");
var clientVal = clientEx.GetValue(client, null);
var viewModelVal = viewModelEx.GetValue(viewModel, null);
bool test = (clientVal == viewModelVal);
```

The bool returns false even when, stepping through the code, clientVal = 1 and viewModelVal = 1.  See attached picture.

[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks guys.

Tim.

EDIT:  Could have given you all the answer.  Glad it was simple in the end.  Thanks alot for your help.  Cheers.

Comment: Are `clientVal` and `viewModelVal` of type `object` ? If so, then your equality comparison is comparing the boxed versions, which should be `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare with `object.Equals()` instead of using reference equality.  Boxed value types will not compare as equal without using `object.Equals()`.  Try this:

```
if (!object.Equals(cinf.GetValue(client, null), vinf.GetValue(viewModel, null)))
```

For example, take this simple case:

```
csharp> object a = 1;
csharp> object b = 1;
csharp> a == b;
false
csharp> object.Equals(a, b);
true
```

Comment: Why don't you call `object.Equals`?

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing to different boxed integers by reference.

Change it to

```
if (!Equals(cinf.GetValue(client, null), vinf.GetValue(viewModel, null))
```

This calls the `static` [`Object.Equals` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx), which will call the `virtual` [`Object.Equals` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) (after checking for `null`) to compare objects by value.

You'll see the same issue for strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is only natural. If you compare to objects together using ==, it will compare their reference which is different.

Use `objectA.Equals(objectB)`.

Comment: This will fail with an exception when `objectA` is null.

Comment: Sure, I assume you check that before, do I have to even mention that??